# Div change position when mouse enters IE9 window ??

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, wordpress-theming

On [this site](http://www.shandon.com.au) I have this weird issue only with IE9.
If you just load the page and you keep your mouse out of the window (or you don't move it), everything is fine.
Whenever you move the mouse, the search box change it's position , scrolling everything down by its height.

It happens ONLY in IE9, and also with JS disabled. 
Any ideas? 
This is the [original theme](http://themes.imperialthemes.com/businessdesign/) where everything is fine also with IE9.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try changing your meta to <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Comment: It has got something to do with float, mind giving it absolute positioning or give it more space to squeeze in.

Comment: You have an aweful lot of css errors, and the structure of the html is very sloppy (when i disable css you see text overlapping the images). Perhaps not the source of this issue, but still..

Comment: What happens if you give .site-navigation a fixed width?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either adding in a CSS Reset.. such as Eric Meyers (this will reset all the default user agent stylesheet styles).

If that doesn't work, you could always use a IE conditional.